# Getting a forloop to complete its iterations (simple)

Tags: c++, string, for-loop

I'm writing a piece of code to capitalise letters after full stop basically, but for some reason, every time I test it, when I type something into the command prompt, the program just stops after I hit the return key. Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks. I'm aware that the loop is meant to be infinite until broken, the idea is that the process of capitalisation will continue until the condition is met where the loop is broken.

```
                if ((text.empty() != 1 ) && (text.at(text.size() - 1) != '!' ) && (text.at(text.size() - 1) != '?') && (text.at(text.size() - 1) != ':' ) && (text.at(text.size()-1 ) != ',' ) && (text.at(text.size() - 1 ) != ';' ) && (text.at(text.size() -1 ) != '=' ) && (text.at(text.size() -1 ) != '-' ) && (text.at(text.size() -1 ) != ')' ) && (text.at(text.size() -1 ) != '}' )  )
        {
            for (i = 0 ;  i >= 0 ; i++)
        {
            text.append("kk") ;
            if (text.find("." , j) < 0 )
                {
                    text.erase(text.size() - 1, 2) ;
                    text2.append(text) ;
                    writer << text2 << endl ;
                    text2.clear() ;
                    j = 0 ;
                    break ;
                }
                else
                {
                    j = text.find("." , j) + 1 ; 
                    k = j + 1;
                    letter = static_cast <int> ( text.at(k) ) ;
                    if (( letter < 123 ) && ( letter > 96 ))
                        {
                            letter = (letter - 32) ;
                            (text.at(k)) = static_cast <char> (letter) ;
                            text.erase(text.size() - 1, 2) ;
                        }
                    else 
                        {
                            text.erase(text.size() - 1, 2) ;
                            continue ; 
                        }
                }
        }
        }
        else 
        if (text == "")
        {
            text2.append("\n") ;
            writer << text2 << endl ;
            text2.clear() ;
        }
        else 
        {
            text2.append(text) ;
            writer << text2 << endl ;
            text2.clear() ;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `for (i = 0 ;  i >= 0 ; i++)` is your problem. That's an infinite loop. It will never end. You need to figure out exactly what you're trying to loop through.

Comment: An infinite loop still breaks when the test conditions are met though doesn't it?

Comment: @user2779581 Yes, you're right that that isn't your problem, but you might as well write `while (true)`, it's more readable and doesn't look like a mistake.

Comment: @jonhopkins well, it *can* end, but we're getting into IB/UB territory - abusing integer overflow is generally a bad thing

Comment: Apologies I'm still new to this, but you mean I should write `while (true) do {etc)` in place of the for statement, is that right?

Comment: An infinite loop can be broken, but seeing as `i` will *never* be less than 0, it will never break from its condition being met.

Comment: @moshbear I was trying to avoid bringing that up for someone who is new to programming haha. But you are correct.

Comment: @user2779581 Yes, but no `do` is necessary. Also that last `continue` is redundant, that's the last command in the loop, it will continue in any case.

Comment: @user2779581 No `do`, just `while`.

Comment: ok thanks, that's not the test condition i was referring to. The only condition that I want the code to break for is for when no "." are found in the code. I'll edit the post to just have everything in it. It's probably messy, but I'm just using the tools I've been given so far :P

Comment: @user2779581 Please look at `<cchar>`, specifically `isalpha`. The `static_cast` is unwarranted complexity here.

Comment: @user2779581 I guess I might have misunderstood your question and jumped to the conclusion that the infinite loop was the problem. After more carefully reading the code, I am guessing that you're trying to only capitalize letters that are right after a period. Correct?

Comment: OK the full set of code is in the question, the part that I'm referring to is about half way down. Thanks moshbear but it's not something I understand yet so I wouldn't feel entirely comfortable using it without knowing what it actually does. Just assume I've been learning this language for about 5-7 hours, and that's the level of person you're working with.

Comment: @johnhopkins that would be correct :)

Comment: You're new to C++ and you're already using `static_cast`? Something feels wrong here.

Comment: Yup, that was on page 40, it has come in handy to be honest though.

Comment: Which C++ book am I adding to my *NO* list this time?

Comment: C++ Programming in Easy Steps. I'm quite liking it myself lol, but then I don't know any different.

Comment: @moshbear If he's going to use anything in `<cctype>`, he'll need `static_cast`.

Comment: @user2779581 Several things: first, your function is far too complex.  Factorize it out into smaller functions.  (Typically, functions will be less than 10 lines.)  Second, the simplest solution here would involve a state machine, to keep track of what you've seen previously.  (You'll want to capitalize after `xxx."`, for example.)  And finally, why all the `xxx.at(i)`?  You aren't catching exceptions (and in this case, you probably couldn't do anything with it if you did catch it), so you shouldn't be using `at`.

Comment: @JamesKanze since when does the usual char->int type promotion fail for `<cctype>`? Possibility of macro implementation of `isXXX`?

Comment: @moshbear The usual char->int conversion works, but gives values which violate the constraints of the `isxxx` functions.  And `isxxx` cannot be a macro in C++.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop goes on a while, increasing j

Then, on this line:

```
        j = text.find("." , j) + 1 ;
```

text.find returns -1, so j becomes zero, so your loop starts over.

Comment: The loop iterator is `i`, not `j`.

Comment: Thanks dude, but now I have another problem. When the program runs and i press enter there is an error and everything shuts down giving the error "terminate called after throwing an instance of `std::out_of_range` `what(): basic_string::at`. Any thoughts?

Comment: @user2779581 You're trying to get the `char` at an index of the string which is either smaller than `0` or bigger than the length of the `string`.

Comment: Yeah I've come across this problem earlier, I'm still unsure what the fix is though. I tried appending the string with two extra characters at the end to make it so that the full stop can't possibly be at the end, I wouldn't know how to then get rid of them again admittedly, but it doesn't work anyway :/

Answer (score 0):

A few tips.

Use autoformatting.  Your formatting was all over the place before I threw it in vim and ='d it.  It helps find bugs.

Second,

```
if ( (text == "end") || (text == "End") || (text == "ENd") || (text == "END") )
```

Use the `tolower` method or `toupper` method to compare case insensitively.

```
if (text == "19823717")
```

You seem to be using this as a magic number to detect the first time around the loop.  Instead move this logic outside of the loop.

```
if ( (text == "end") || (text == "End") || (text == "ENd") || (text == "END") ) 
  {
    writer.close() ;
    cout << "End of session" << endl ; break ;
  }
  else 
    if (...
```

The bare else here scares me.  It might not be doing what you're intending.  It's probably much better to wrap this in `{}s`

```
letter = static_cast <int> ( text.at(k) ) ;
```

You don't need this cast.  A `char` can be treated as a number directly.  `char a = 97;` for instance.

```
if (( letter < 123 ) && ( letter > 96 ))
```

Use `toupper` instead.

Beyond that though.  I don't know what your issue actually is.  It's likely a subtle logical error that will become obvious as you clean up these other problems.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I'm a complete beginner and don't actually understand what you mean when you say `tolower` and `toupper` I wish I could implement them though! I've changed what you said about the magic number, it wasn't actually necessary at all, I just moved the first statements out and it works fine. I've updated the one bit of code that I have left to fix, if you could take another look I'd appreciate it. I'm even like going through the whole process and I just can't see where the mistake is being made. So frustrating!